# previous and next item in list vb

Tags: vb.net

im new to vb and wanted to know how to scroll through a list that i have made. the list "currentOrder" (this list contains items from another list called "item" which has the item's ".name",".price" and ".comment" to make one item in the list.) 
 is brought into another windows form where it is split into 3 different text boxes ("txtEditName", "txtEditComments" and "txtEditCost") one holds the items name another the price and another the comment and i was wanting to have 2 buttons to go to the previous item in the list and one to go to the next item while swapping the variables to the new item in the lists details.

```
Public item As New List(Of Product)
Public CurrentOrder = New List(Of Product)

Dim Chips As New Product("Chips", 5.0, "")
Dim FriedDimSim As New Product("Fried Dim Sim", 1.0, "")
Dim SteamedDimSim As New Product("Steamed Dim Sim", 1.0, "")
Dim PotatoCake As New Product("Potato Cake", 1.0, "")
...`
```

when a button on the GUI is then clicked, it add the corresponding item to the "CurrentOrder" list.

when the button "btnEdit" is clicked it then does the following

```
Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    For Each item As Product In CurrentOrder
        Edit.txtEditName.Text = item.name + Environment.NewLine
        Edit.txtEditComments.Text = item.comment + Environment.NewLine
        Edit.txtEditCost.Text = item.price & Environment.NewLine
    Next

    Edit.Show()
```

so i would like help with the coding of the previous and next buttons to help me access the item before and after in the "CurrentOrder" list

thanks

Comment: You can access a list via index: `Dim product = CurrentOrder(index)`. So you just need to store the current-index in a field. Then you can increment/decrement that field in the button-click event-handler and then call a method that displays the current product. If `index`is `-1` after decrement you can set it to `CurrentOrder.Count - 1`. If it's `CurrentOrder.Count` after increment you can set it to 0.

Comment: You can bind your list to a `BindingSource` and use the `Current` property to access the current item.  The `BindingSource` has `MoveNext` and `MovePrevious` methods that you can call to navigate the data.  You can associate the `BindingSource` with a `BindingNavigator` to provide a navigation UI.  If you bind the `BindingSource` to the UI then there's no need to write code to move data into and out of your controls.